# How to get PDF structure in xml format

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pdf, data-science

[image] Below is my code, where I am converting pdf to xml format.
But this gives me xml formated file only if I used XFA-PDF(pdf form) formated pdf.
I need to convert any type of pdf to xml format and xml contain information about text value, tables, images, objects/drawings and their x,y co-ordinates.
Is there any way to get this type of xml from pdf?

Thank you!

```
import PyPDF2
import re
def findInDict(needle, haystack):
    for key in haystack.keys():
        try:
            value=haystack[key]
        except:
            continue
        if key==needle:
            return value
        if isinstance(value,dict):          
            x=findInDict(needle,value)            
            if x is not None:
                return x

 

def create_xml_PDFform(xfa):
    for i in range(0,len(xfa)):
        try:
            xml = xfa[i].getObject().getData()
            f = open('C:\\Users\\tanvi_karekar\\'+str(pdf_file)+'.xml', 'ab')
            f.write(xml)
            f.close()
        except:
            continue

 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_file = 'sampleDoc3'
    pdf_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\tanvi_karekar\\'+str(pdf_file)+'.pdf'
    pdfobject = open(pdf_file_path,'rb')
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfobject)
    xfa = findInDict('/XFA',pdf.resolved_objects) 
    create_xml_PDFform(xfa)
```

Is there any way to get this type of xml from pdf? or any library to get pdf structure?

This is my pdf looks like.

Comment: Your code does **not** convert PDF to XML. The XFA it extracts may or may not correspond to the regular PDF content. Often the PDF content of files with XFA streams amounts to "You need Adobe Acrobat to read this file".

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [pdfminer.six](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). You can dump the XML, if this helps with the command line tool: `dumppdf.py -a example.pdf >PDF_TEXT.xml`

Compare the manuals on the page, here is one as an example:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer
for page_layout in extract_pages("example.pdf"):
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
            print(element.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank You! @Hermann12 . It gives pdf structure, but it not constructed as per their positions. If I have image and text in pdf. It gives text first and then images in xml. I want pdf structure in tree format as it is in pdf.